# OpenGL-ES World Cordinates to Screen Cordinates

Tags: android, screen, opengl-es-2.0

I'm developing an android app that display OpenGL-ES stuff I add one cube in center of the opengl-es screen, but  when some click happend I need to get the screen cordinates and compare position of object to x-y clicked position.

---

As of now I have those that I believe with those I can get screen cordinates of object

```
final float[] projectionMatrix
final float[] modelViewMatrix
```

these are float arrays with 16 index based size.

---

Does someone know who to calculate screen cordinates based on those two arrays. 
I heard about GLUProject but I don't know how to use it.

Solution in Java would be great,but If someone has any solution in another language please post it.

Comment: the 16 floats represent a 4x4 matrix. Multiply `projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * position` and divide by the `w` component. Note, that the combination of tags on your questions is not valid: There is no OpenGL on android. You most probably mean [tag:opengl-es]?

Comment: yeep opengl-es sorry, may I ask you question I know what is
projectionMatrix and modelViewMatrix
but what is position (which position do u refer) and 
w component ?